# Entity Framework 6: Erro ao obter registro no SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Consigo inserir registros no banco normalmente, porém, ao tentar obter, dá erro no EF.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        new ClienteConsole().ConsoleListarCliente(1);
    }
}
```

```
public class ClienteConsole {
    public void ConsoleListarCliente(int matricula)
    {
        try
        {
            var dao = new ClienteDao();
            var cliente = dao.ObterCliente(matricula);
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ClienteDao
{
    private MyContext _db = new MyContext();

    public void Cadastrar(Cliente cliente)
    {
        _db.Set<Cliente>().Add(cliente); //Sem erro.
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Cliente ObterCliente(int matricula)
    {
        return _db.Set<Cliente>().Find(matricula); //Erro.
    }
    ...
}
```

> Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada.
>
> ```
> em System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,
>    Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>
> em System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[]
>    parameters, Object[] arguments)
>
> em System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,
>    Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap(Translator translator, Type elementType, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>
> em System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>
> em System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>
> em System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(WrappedEntityKey key, String keyValuesParamName)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
>
> em System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
>
> em MyProject.Infra.Data.Dao.ClienteDao.ObterCliente(Int32 matricula) na D:\Raphael\C#\MyProject\MyProject.Infra.Data\Dao\ClienteDao.cs:linha 28
>
> em MyProject.Console.Console.ClienteConsole.ConsoleListarCliente(Int32 matricula) na D:\Raphael\C#\MyProject\MyProject.Console\Console\ClienteConsole.cs:linha 120
> ```

Após retirar a estrutura "try-catch", a seguinte exceção é lançada:

> InvalidOperationException: The class 'Cliente' has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: Tem alguma informação nas inner exceptions?

Comment: O id de cliente é realmente um int?

Comment: @LiNQ as inners exceptions seria a Exception? pois coloquei somente isso no catch.

Comment: @GabrielColetta sim, o id do cliente é um int

Comment: @Raphael Que catch que você diz?

Comment: do "Try catch".

Comment: Isso eu sei, meu filho. Quero saber onde tá esse `catch`, porque no código da pergunta não tem nada disso.

Comment: Ah sim, no método Main eu chamei esse método passando o try-catch.

Comment: vou editar o código.

Comment: @Raphael Beleza, então tira esse negócio (o try-catch) porque ele tá escondendo os detalhes da exceção.

Comment: Esse é um dos maiores problemas da sub-utilização do mecanismo de exceções.

Comment: @Raphael Tire esse try-catch, execute novamente, poste os detalhes do erro

Comment: @LINQ adicionei.

Comment: Faça um construtor para Cliente protected, o framework precisa de um construtor sem parâmetros.

Comment: Ah, agora deu certo! obrigado @GabrielColetta e LINQ, não sabia disso.

Comment: @Raphael Fica a dica pra vida: nunca capture uma exceção se não for fazer nada com ela.

Comment: @LINQ Ta certo! hehe obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Entity Framework exige que exista um construtor sem parâmetros nos models.

```
public class Cliente
{
    public Cliente() { }
}
```